# how to tokenize the the following infix expression in php?

Tags: php, regex

infix expression : false and true or true and (false or false or not true)

I want an array containing elements:

false", "and", "true", "or", "true", "and", "(", "false", "or", "false", "or", "not", "true", ")

I can not use space as the delimiter because the parentheses may not be separated from the next or proceeding true/false with space.

Comment: Please share any failed attempts. And explain what you actually want to do (breaking out various `true` and `false` tokens doesn't seem very useful), or how you want to utilize it. (Else please refrain from follow-up questions on how to actually parse and interpret something entirely different.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the below code which uses positive lookahead and lookbehind,

```
<?php
$yourstring = "false and true or true and (false or false or not true)";
$regex = '~\s|(?<=\()|(?=\))~';
$splits = preg_split($regex, $yourstring);
print_r($splits);
?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => false
    [1] => and
    [2] => true
    [3] => or
    [4] => true
    [5] => and
    [6] => (
    [7] => false
    [8] => or
    [9] => false
    [10] => or
    [11] => not
    [12] => true
    [13] => )
)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Avinash. I was exactly looking for this :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged this as [regex](/questions/tagged/regex), I assume you want to use regular expressions?

How about this?

```
(false|true|\(|\)|and|or|not)
```

For example

```
$input = "false and true or true and (false or false or not true)";
$regex = '/(false|true|\(|\)|and|or|not)/';
preg_match_all($regex, $input, $tokens);
var_dump($tokens);
```

Answer (score 0):

What I think you are trying to do is to build an [Abstract Syntax Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) to evaluate a boolean expression.

You can do it [library](https://github.com/hafriedlander/php-peg) that given a [grammar](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/10558/grammar-for-describing-boolean-expressions-with-and-or-and-not) gives you the abstract tree.

Answer (score 0):

```
([a-zA-Z0-9]+)|(\()|(\))
```

You can use this regex.This will give a list with values like "",undefined which you can remove by using  underscore _.compact().

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/sB4kE6/3